# I can´t send POST from 8080 to 3000

Tags: oracle, vue.js

`CRUD APP dosen`t send anything to my API. Do you have an idea what the Problem could be?

On localhost:8080
I get Status 200 + "Transmission failed"

On localhost:3000
NETWORK-TAB give me Status 200. Got nothing from localhost:8080
I also checked my Cache.

Backend: (localhost:3000)
set Cors
set body-parser
Checked connection to DB is running and fetching data from the database.

Firewall:
1.disabled than tried again... nothing.
2.created incoming and outgoing rules for port 8080 and for 3000. They are active.

```
Frontend: (localhost:8080) Vue:

<template>
<div class="home">  

<h1>Test</h1>

<div class="user-add">
  <h2>Add user</h2>
  <input type="text" v-model="name" /> <br />
  <button @click="storeUser">Store</button>
</div>
</div>

</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    name:'CRUD2',
    data() {
    return {
    user: {},  
    };
  },
  mounted() { 
  },
  methods: {
    async storeUser() {
  try {
    const user = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3000/easy", 
      {
        name: this.name,
      }
    );

      console.log(user)
    if (user.status === 201) {
      console.log("Transmission successful
");
    } else {
      console.error("Transmission failed
");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
},
    
}
};
</script>

Backend: index.js Node(express) localhost(3000):

const express = require("express");
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080'
}))

/* I tried also do this..
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    req.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});*/
app.use(bodyParser.json());

oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;

//GET 

app.get("/easy", async (req, res) => {
    let con;

    try {
        con = await oracledb.getConnection({
            user: "user",
            password: "password",
            connectString: "h2922093.stratoserver.net:1521/orcl.stratoserver.net"
        });

        const data = await con.execute(`SELECT * FROM EASY`);
        res.json(data.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    } finally {
        if (con) {
            await con.close();
        }
    }
});


//POST

app.post("/easy", async (req, res) => {
    let con;

    try {
        con = await oracledb.getConnection({
            user: "user",
            password: "password",
            connectString: "h2922093.stratoserver.net:1521/orcl.stratoserver.net"
        });

        
        const body = req.body;
        const sql = `INSERT INTO EASY (NAME) 
                   VALUES (:name)`;

        const result = await con.execute(sql, [
            body.name,

        ]);

        if(result.rowsAffected){
            res.send({
                message: `${result.rowsAffected} row(s) inserted`,
                status: 201
            })
        }else {
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }

        
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    } finally {
        if (con) {
            await con.close();
        }
    }
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server started on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

[localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oid5.jpg)

[localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlV2d.jpg)

[localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLtLC.jpg)
`

`I tried:

Check my code in Backend;
Check my code in Frontend;

Backend: (localhost:3000)
-set Cors
-set body-parser
-Checked connection to DB is running and fetching data from the database.

Firewall:
1.disabled than tried again... nothing.
2.created incoming and outgoing rules for port 8080 and for 3000. They are active.

I´m expecting:

to send POST {test2} from localhost:8000 to localhost:3000 and INSERT test2 into Table EASY`

Comment: Outgoing firewall rules? Those ports are only used for *incoming* traffic to the server. Client-side (source) ports are *always* random. Your front-end connection is from a random client port on your workstation *to* port 8080. Your back-end connection should always be from a random client port *on the front-end server* to port 3000 on the back-end server. That said, disabling your firewall entirely should have worked if blocked ports was your only problem, so it is likely you have more going on. Can't tell from what you've provided.

Comment: Hey pmdba, thank you very much  for your comment. Concerning the rules you are right. It should work but it  dosen‘t work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with Postman:
Get Request works properly that means I got only the one Object and Status 200 back

```
[{
    “NAME”: “Test”
}]
Post Request http: //localhost:3000/easy: I send it as a JSON : { “name”: “test2”} and I got also the message Status 201. But that is strange because nothing was inserted into my table or see anything on my localhost:3000/easy except the one Object with the name: Test.
    {
        "message": "1 row(s) inserted",
        "status": 201
    }
```

I set also the headers:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

And I changed the CORS Library to `cors-express: const cors = require('cors-express');`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Issue myself:

Frontend:

```
async addData() {
    //You can give an id for your input (id="nameInput")

    const name = nameInput.value;
    nameInput.value = "";

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/easy', {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: name
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
     }
}
```

Backend:
And please not forget in backend in your index.js file to define (and install of course the pakets):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;
    
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```